# How to fix this ULN2003 circuit?

Tags: uln2003

[image]

I am trying to understand the working of the [ULN2003](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/uln2003a), but I can't run this circuit properly. Please help me understand why this is not working.

Comment: Your simulated LED could be burnt out by not having a series resistor.

Comment: i have also tried with resistor in series with LED but that is also not working

Comment: remove the ULN2003 ... start with an LED, resistor and a power supply ... when you achieve illumination, then add the ULN2003

Comment: Since the input and output of the ULN2003 have no current then your Sim software does not have a model for it. The datasheet of a ULN2003 shows that it is a simple darlington transistor and a few resistors.

Comment: @Audioguru worse even, the sim software assumes a load of nonsense. There's practically 0 current flowing through the LED, still it exhibits a 1.8 V drop; that's not an LED, that's a magical bad programming component. Someone used a simple script instead of a proper component model. (that's not Kamran's fault, but goes to stress how little sense it makes to rely on the simulation instead of understanding here)

Answer (score 1):

1. you're missing a series resistor for your LED. You'll burn both the LED and probably the ULN2003 that way
2. Don't use an ULN2003 at all. You don't need something with a large current gain, nor something with free-wheeling diodes. What you *really* can't use is the fact that the ULN2003 is a Darlington array – that means high voltage drop within the ULN2003, which means more power gets converted to heat within your ULN2003 than your LED uses. So, replace that thing. It's something that has died with the 1980s.
3. Especially, you don't even need the 12 V source - your LED has a forward voltage of 1.8 V it seems¹, so you can directly control them from 5V.

All in all, since your question is "how to fix this circuit": Throw away your circuit. Simple NPN transistors with a base resistor and a resistor in series with each LED (or LED string) are the way to go here.

---

¹ and your simulator has a very inconsistent semiconductor model, but that's a different story.